# Error occur during User's Sign Out in Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My website uses Ionic and Angular Frameworks with Firestore database. The signout functionality is doing its job but unfortunately, after the function occur an error occur while user signout in his/her account.

**The error message:**

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

[image]

**app.component.ts** - this is where the user press the logout button

```
  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {

    this.appSub = this.authService.user$.subscribe(async user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.userId = user.userId;
      try {
        this.userPhoto = user.userPhoto;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('No User Photo');
      }
    });

  }
  //Logout Button
  onLogout(){

      this.authService.signOut();

  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router
    ) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState
      .pipe(
        switchMap( user => {
          if (user) {
            return this.afs.doc<User>(`user/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
          } else {
            return of(null);
          }
        })
      )

  } //end of constructor

  //Sign Out Function
  async signOut(){

    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      spinner: 'crescent',
      showBackdrop: true
    });
    loading.present();

    this.afAuth.signOut()
      .then(() => {
        loading.dismiss();
        
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  } // end of signout
```

Is there anyway to avoid these error?

Comment: before logging out You should unsubscribe from all firebase observable then execute your logout function.

Comment: @ZrelliMajdi where can I put this unsubcribe function. In my component I unsubscribe already the ```this.appSub```

Comment: my You have a stream of data not (unsubscribed) and has an auth user permission

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `this.appSub.unsubscribe()` in your logout function, you can refer to the [link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/377#issuecomment-234749207) for more details.

Check for the firebase version as mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2838#issuecomment-850919373), reverting back to firebase @8.6.1 would resolve the issue.
For more reference you can refer to the [documentation](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) where how to fix firestore error has been briefly explained.

Comment: @minalisa Posted an answer, Is it helpful?